# Time dilation at a point between two spherical masses that nearly touch

Tags: spacetime, curvature, time-dilation

I need to apologize for asking the question trough very "blunt" and fantasy scenario, but I believe it will help me to understand better how the connection between mass and time works  (well not mass and time but space-time curvature...sorry about the wording, English is not my native language and I sometimes struggle to use correct words for ideas/thoughts even in my own language).

The scenario: Lets assume we have two identical Earths placed in the space 100 meters from each other. The observer is placed directly in between them, so 50 meters away from surface of each (the distance is really not that important, I just want it to be small enough). If I understand correctly - at that point in space (space-time) the g force (the final generated gravitational attraction) is zero as there are 1 g forces in opposite directions.

The question: Even thou the g force is zero, the time dilation (compared to being 50 meters above "single" Earth) is actually as if the observer was on a surface of planet twice as heavy as Earth?

Do I understand it correctly?

Thank you in advance for your answer

Comment: Time dilation compared to what?

Comment: @WillO: Presumably compared to a distant, static observer.

Comment: As a way to think of this.  Keep in mind that a dust cloud in space, a million kilometers long but with the same total mass as Earth, would have the same gravity and time dilation as Earth.  But if you were floating in the exact middle of the dust cloud, then you would feel no gravitational pull in any direction.  So think of your two planets a just a dust cloud with only two particles.

Comment: @foolishmuse “a dust cloud in space, a million kilometers long but with the same total mass as Earth, would have the same gravity and time dilation as Earth” What makes you think that?

Comment: I assume your 2 Earths are orbiting each other, otherwise your observer will get crushed between them in 3 or 4 seconds. ;) FWIW, neglecting atmospheric friction, 2 bodies of Earth's mass and radius would orbit at that distance with a period of 170 minutes, according to https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/orbital-period

Comment: @G.Smith   A question that I posed in Reddit last year.   Answer: Gravity is solely based on mass (technically, the stress-energy tensor).

However, an object will experience gravitation based on its distance from the source of gravity, and that's where density is relevant. If you're far away, a dust cloud, a gas giant, and a rocky planet, will have the same effect. But you can get much closer to the center of a denser object.

If you're in the cloud, or digging below the surface of a planet, some of the gravity below you is canceled out by the gravity of the mass above you.

Comment: @foolishmuse What you just wrote doesn’t imply what you previously wrote. BTW, Reddit is a terrible place to learn physics.

Answer (score 3):

If there were two Earths separated by 100 meters, there *would* be time dilation (compared with time at infinite distance away) at the midpoint between them, and it would be almost but not exactly twice as much as for one Earth, even though there is no net force there.

This is because gravitational time dilation depends on gravitational *potential*, not on gravitational *force*.

It is not *exactly* twice because in General Relativity gravitational fields from two sources do not linearly superpose the way they do in Newtonian gravity. GR is a *non*linear theory, but for weak fields like Earth’s the nonlinearities can generally be ignored.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I think I get it now. So if I oversimplify this - the answer to my question is yes...or close to it (if the forces are linear, which is basically not possible). But I understand now that in the general principal - what is relevant is gravitational potential not force. And I understand better the difference between gravitational potential and gravitational force.Thanks again.

Comment: One may say that the gravitational potential depends on the time dilation, but the meaning is the same +1